Excel 365 - TEXTJOIN, Sort & Unique values across columns into one cell
I have 10 columns that have a list of email names, these email labels are pulled from another cell based on counties.  Because the counties are divided up by regions, the names overlap (duplicates).
I want to use textjoin to concatanate values into single cell, use semicolon separator, list unique values, sort them in descending order.
I've attempted the similar examples on this site but they haven't given me the result I am looking for.
=TEXTJOIN("; ",TRUE,UNIQUE($A2:$J2)))
This formula gives me the values in each column but I still get duplicates and they are not sorted.


I use textjoin with unique and sort functions all the time including look-ups and accessing large amounts of data. I have not experienced this issue before with data in rows so decided to try out a few things.
The simple answer is that you are confusing the formula with columns instead of rows. When you are joining across columns it is not looking at the values as a single dataset but separate datasets (one per column).
Your question intrigued me so I found part of the answer elsewhere. I thought you'd have to transpose the full table but that can be achieved do so through another function. :) ooohhh new function
You mention wanting a sorted unique list but do not include sort in your formula. If the first instances of your data are in sorted order the unique list will look sorted otherwise you do need to add it as a separate function.
This is a formula I frequently use to get sorted unique strings. It can be modified for multiple criteria or data across columns
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,UNIQUE(SORT(IF((D2=sheet1!E:E),sheet1!B:B,""))))
I tried 4 different formulas with the same data set. I just made generic values to make it easier to identify the different values. 1, 2, 3, and 4
2DEF; 3GHI; 4JKL; 1ABC; 3GHI; 4JKL; 2DEF; 1ABC; 1ABC
When data in is across columns instead of down a column in rows: You need an additional step to get unique and/or sort. Add TRANSPOSE to make excel think data is in only one column.

TEXTJOIN("; ",TRUE,UNIQUE(TRANSPOSE(A1:I1))) will give: 2DEF; 3GHI; 4JKL; 1ABC
TEXTJOIN("; ",TRUE,UNIQUE(SORT(TRANSPOSE(A1:I1)))) will give: 1ABC; 2DEF; 3GHI; 4JKL

When data in down a column in rows (same data set with just in 1 to 9 instead of A to I)
3. TEXTJOIN("; ",TRUE,UNIQUE(D1:D9)) will give: 2DEF; 3GHI; 4JKL; 1ABC
4. TEXTJOIN("; ",TRUE,UNIQUE(SORT(D1:D9))) will give: 1ABC; 2DEF; 3GHI; 4JKL
For your current table #2 would work best but #4 is the best if table is transposed. For large datasets it is better to have the data going down the column to make it easier to filter, read and manipulate the data.
I know you asked 4 months ago but hopefully this helps someone else with the same question. :) It is sometimes hard to find this formula so cleanly because authors what to use other functions.
There are usually 3 ways to work a formula in excel and people will fiercely defend the functions they use most. This and XLOOKUP are always my goto formulas. MS365 has the most current functions with some not found in other/older excel versions. They made several frequently used functions easier by creating new versions that use less resources, are succinct and easy to nest together. BTW: TEXTSPLIT is the flipside of TEXTJOIN.

This works in my sheet.
=TEXTJOIN(", ",,SORT(UNIQUE(A28:L28,TRUE),,,TRUE))

EDIT:
For descending order:
=TEXTJOIN(", ",,SORT(UNIQUE(A28:L28,TRUE),,-1,TRUE))


